# Grails assets file is not minified

Tags: angularjs, grails

I have included grails-asset and angular-annotate-grails-asset-pipeline plugin.

But I am getting this error

```
.Error
|
WAR packaging error: No signature of method: static asset.pipeline.AssetHelper.getAssetPathsByPlugin() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Error |
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.ScriptExitException
Error |
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
Error |
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
Error |
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
Error |
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
Error |
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
Error |
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
Error |
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:57)
Error |
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
Error |
at 

    org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
    Error |
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:391)
    Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:207)
    Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:68)
    Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    Error |
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
    Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:166)
    Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
    Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    Error |
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
    Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:207)
    Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:68)
    Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    Error |
    at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
    Error |
    at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
    Error |
    at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    Error |
    at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    Error |
    at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
    Error |
    at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
    Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
    Error |
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
    Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:809)
    Error |
    at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
    Error |
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObject$invokeMethod.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    Error |
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObject$invokeMethod.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    Error |
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:591)
    Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:166)
    Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
    Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:61)
    Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
    Error |
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
    Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeWithGantInstance(GrailsScriptRunner.java:780)
    Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptFile(GrailsScriptRunner.java:572)
    Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptWithCaching(GrailsScriptRunner.java:471)
    Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptWithCaching(GrailsScriptRunner.java:422)
    Error |
    at org.grails.ide.api.impl.GrailsConnectorImpl.executeCommand(GrailsConnectorImpl.java:160)
    Error |
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.process.GrailsProcess.run(GrailsProcess.java:130)
    Error |
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.process.GrailsProcess.main(GrailsProcess.java:93)
    Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:236)
    Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:264)
    Error |
    Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.ScriptExitException
    Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.api.BaseSettingsApi.exit(BaseSettingsApi.java:370)
    Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.api.BaseSettingsApi$exit$1.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.packaging.GrailsProjectWarCreator.packageWar(GrailsProjectWarCreator.groovy:126)
    Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.packaging..
```

My configuration is

compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.9"

compile ":angular-annotate-asset-pipeline:2.0.1"

when i try to add

compile ":asset-pipeline:2.0.19"

which is latest then i am not getting error but file is not minified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try running `grails clean-all` command. It cleared the issue for me after upgrading to asset-pipeline:2.0.19.