# Disable Minifying in Gradle

Tags: grails, gradle, asset-pipeline, minify

How to disable minifying of .css and .js in my gradle configuration?

OBS: Grails v.2.4.0, Gradle v.1.12 and asset-pipeline v.1.8.7

I have been trying some of the following options:

- In Config.groovy
  `grails.assets.minifyJs = false
  grails.assets.minifyCss = false
  // as well as some others, but without success`
- Commenting pipeline-plugin in dependencies.gradle
- Commenting assetCompiler.compile() in _AssetCompiler.groovy

What I expect to achieve by doing this is less build time for local deploys and make a new Task for generating a new .war without minifying while still having the old 'war' option for a complete production build.

Answer (score 0):

Run grails `clean-all` command. It cleared the issue for me after upgrading to asset-pipeline

Ref: Reverse case for these guys: [Grails assets not minified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27562000/grails-assets-file-is-not-minified)